# Maximizing sum of homogeneous functions of order one over a polytope

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Let $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be 
concave, increasing (i.e., if $x\geq y$ where the inequality is entry wise, we have $f_i(x)\geq f_i(y)$), and a
 homogeneous function of order one for $i=1,\dots,n$. 
Further suppose that for any $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where the first entry is zero (i.e., $y(1)=0$), $f_i(y)=0$ for all $i$.

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\{x_i\in \mathbb{R}^n\}}  \quad & \sum_i f_i(x_i) \\
s.t.  \quad & \sum_i x_i =b \\
& x_i \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Is it the case that 
at the optimal solution we generically have $x_i=0$ for all but one $i$? Observe that this trivially holds if $f_i$ are linear.

Comment: $x_i$ are vectors, see the domain of $f_i$.  By increasing, I mean increasing in each coordinate. Question updated to clarify these points.

Comment: Correct  -- question updated accordingly.

Comment: What about the case $f_i(z)= z^i$ (the $i$-th coordinate of $z$) for all $i$. Then the optimal solution is $(b^1e_1,\ldots,b^ne_n)$ where $b^i$ are the coordinates of $b$ and $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ the canonical basis.

Comment: in the linear case, it is true there may exist a solution where all $x_i$ are positive. But this is not true generically. 

Your second point is correct. Which made me realize that some of the additional structure I have in the problem is necessary for the question to be interesting. I'm updating the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean by generically. Regarding the additional assumption, it seems still possible to build linear cases where for every $i$,  $f_i(y)$ does not depend on $y(1)$.

Comment: if $f_i(y)$ does not depend on $y(1)$, then by the assumption $f_i=0$. Sorry, it was not clear what I mean by generically. Consider a parameterized family of functions $\{f_i=g_i^s\}$, where $s\in S$ and where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^k$.  Let $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue measure, and $Z\subset S$ be the set of parameters for which at optimal solution we have $x_i,x_j>0$ for $i\neq j$. Is it the case that $\mu(Z)=0$?

Comment: I don't know, it probably depends on $g_i^s$ and $S$, etc. My intuition tells me that it should be possible to construct such a parametrized family where $g_i^s$ is linear for every $i,s$ and differentiable in $s$ such that the optimal solution is positive for every $s$.